# Grouping Excel 1004 Error

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do:
I have a excel sheet with 9 columns. In the excel sheet to be grouped by column A

What I did so far

```
Public Sub GroupCells()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim firstBlankRow As Integer, lastBlankRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String
    Dim neighborColumnValue As String


    Set myRange = Range("A1:A1000")
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, myRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    firstBlankRow = 0
    lastBlankRow = 0
    'for every row in the range
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column).Value
        neighborColumnValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column - 1).Value

        If (IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "") Then
            'if cell is blank and firstBlankRow hasn't been assigned yet
            If firstBlankRow = 0 Then
                firstBlankRow = currentRow
            End If
        ElseIf Not (IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "") Then
            'if the cell is not blank and its neighbor's (to the left) value is 0,
            'and firstBlankRow hasn't been assigned, then this is the firstBlankRow
            'to consider for grouping
            If neighborColumnValue = 0 And firstBlankRow = 0 Then
                firstBlankRow = currentRow
            ElseIf neighborColumnValue <> 0 And firstBlankRow <> 0 Then
                'if firstBlankRow is assigned and this row has a value with a neighbor
                'who isn't 0, then the cell one row above this one is to be considered
                'the lastBlankRow to include in the grouping
                lastBlankRow = currentRow - 1
            End If
        End If

        'if first AND last blank rows have been assigned, then create a group
        'then reset the first/lastBlankRow values to 0 and begin searching for next
        'grouping
        If firstBlankRow <> 0 And lastBlankRow <> 0 Then
            Range(Cells(firstBlankRow, myRange.Column), Cells(lastBlankRow, myRange.Column)).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Group
            firstBlankRow = 0
            lastBlankRow = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

For this solution i am using the code of a fallow stackoverflow /co programmer called "Sam"
[image]
I go the error 1004 when i exceute my macro in excel

Comment: What is the line of the error?

Comment: Did you get error on this line (`neighborColumnValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column - 1).Value`)?

Comment: @DavidG  please dont get me wrong i dont use much excel vba but excel does not point me to the line or did i miss some settings that i have to enable to do that ?

Comment: You can see the error line when you click Debug on the pop out window.  Also, since you start your range on A1, that `myrange.Column - 1` will make it to nowhere because there is no such column before A.

Comment: @ian0411 i see so if id remove the -1 i get the error "type mismatch (Error 13)"

Comment: Again, try to tell us the line of the new error.

Comment: If you remove the -1, you will make both `currentRowValue` and `neighborColumnValue` the same.  I don't believe that is what you are trying to do...

Comment: Your next error will be on this line: `If neighborColumnValue = 0 And firstBlankRow = 0 Then` and this is because the `neighborColumnValue` variable is defined as String and they can't be compared to integer values.

Comment: Usually you get this error because you're trying to copy & paste filtered data programmatically, and Excel doesn't like certain ways that is done. We need to see what line you're getting the error on. Put your cursor inside the Subroutine and step-through it via the F8 key and tell us what line you get the error 1004 on.

Comment: @DavidG Thats where it crashes now  If neighborColumnValue = 0 And firstBlankRow = 0 Then
                firstBlankRow = currentRow

Comment: You will probably want to change to this `If neighborColumnValue = "" And firstBlankRow = 0 Then` and also two lines below too because `neighborColumnValue` is defined as a String.  But not really sure what you are trying to accomplish here...

Comment: @ian0411 what i am trying to do is simply group the whole sheet by column a that's it

Comment: So this is solved?  Anyway, here is a great resource (https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/313605-vba-grouping-rows-based-criteria.html) with a sample code that may help you to do the grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remving the minus 1 from `neighborColumnValue` 
you've set your column to A via `myRange` 
You cant take a column away from A

```
neighborColumnValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column - 1).Value
```

Becomes

```
neighborColumnValue = Cells(currentRow, myRange.Column).Value
```

Comment: hey thanks alot for the time and effort but this does not help me still getting an error

Comment: Type mismatch (Error 13)

Comment: could you possibly post an example of your data set in that case. Just because the data set i used that got rid of the error. :)

Comment: as @ian0411 has said in his comments you either need to change what `neighborColumnValue` is declared as or change it `=""`